# Single page app with web component

Tags: dart, polymer

I'm writing a web-based project using polymer.dart. When I use anchor elements inside a web component, it always redirects to the URL prefixed with component name which is not exists. Do I need to add routing logic in every web component and prevent this default behavior ? Or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes...or use a framework that does this sort of thing. This is not a problem web components tries to solve. A link (anywhere) in your will need to have `preventDefault()` called, otherwise the browser will invoke its default behavior. In the case of a link, that's to navigate to the target.

Comment: Do I need to insert pages manually into DOM (using createElement etc.), or use conditional template? Which one is the recommended way and why ?